# How to join two tables which don't have any relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which hold two different types of invoices. I need to create a query which counts the number of invoices per client from both the tables.

Also each invoice types have other tables which hold information about an invoice which a JOIN statement is added on to each SELECT statement. But the two tables don't share any detailed invoice tables.

So this is what the schema looks like: 
invoiceA has a relation with serviceInvoice and invoiceDetail.
invoiceB has a relation with packageInvoice and supportInvoice.

I didn't include any of the JOINs, but this is a rough idea of what my query looks like.

```
SELECT
    i.client_id, COUNT(i.invoice_num)
FROM 
(
    SELECT client_id, invoice_num, cff_num FROM invoiceA
    UNION
    SELECT client_id, invoice_num, cff_num FROM invoiceB
)i
WHERE
    i.cff_num IS NULL
GROUP BY
    i.client_id
```

This query seems weird and inefficient, I wanted to do a LEFT JOIN on invoiceB, but there are rows which have the same client_id in both tables. Is there anything I can do to optimize this?

Comment: That query seems neither weird nor inefficient.

Comment: I would suggest 'UNION ALL' as an optimization, as long as you're not actually looking for a distinct operation on your union (I would find it odd, but you know your invoice_num better than I do).

Comment: You can move the predicate "where cff_num is null" into both parts of the union all section. This will filter out those rows before the union. (And you don't need to select it from invoiceA or invoiceB then.)

Answer (score 0):

Store this in a view and you can select from it whenever you like:

```
SELECT
    client_id,
    COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM invoiceA
WHERE
    cff_num IS NULL
GROUP BY
    client_id

UNION

SELECT
    client_id,
    COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM invoiceB
WHERE
    cff_num IS NULL
GROUP BY
    client_id
```